# How to check for variable character in string and match it with another string of same length?

Tags: c#

I have a rather complex issue that I'am unable to figure out.

I'm getting a set of string every 10 seconds from another process in which the first set has first 5 characters constant, next 3 are variable and can change. And then another set of string in which first 3 are variable and next 3 are constant.

I want to compare these values to a fixed string to check if the first 5 char matches in 1st set of string (ABCDE*** == ABCDEFGH) and ignore the last 3 variable characters while making sure the length is the same. Eg : if (ABCDE*** == ABCDEDEF) then condition is true, but if (ABCDE*** == ABCDDEFG) then the condition is false because the first 5 char is not same, also if (ABCDE*** == ABCDEFV) the condition should be false as one char is missing.

I'm using the * in fixed string to try to make the length same while comparing.

Comment: Please show the code you've tried so far.

Comment: I have not tried anything, I dont know how to do this.

Comment: "I have not tried anything, I dont know how to do this." normally you take a big problem and break it into smaller parts. then you try to research each individual part and solve it one by one like: 1) C# how to compare length of strings, 2) C# how to compare first letters of string, 3) C# how to get only part of string and so on...

Comment: This do-able using regex. This official Microsoft documentation explains it with examples. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match?view=net-6.0

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's always a good idea to make an abstraction. Here I've made a simple function that takes the pattern and the value and makes a check:

```cs
bool PatternMatches(string pattern, string value)
{
    // The null string doesn't match any pattern
    if (value == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    // If the value has a different length than the pattern, it doesn't match.
    if (pattern.Length != value.Length)
    {
        return false;
    }
    // If both strings are zero-length, it's considered a match
    bool result = true;
    // Check every character against the pattern
    for (int i = 0; i< pattern.Length; i++)
    { 
        // Logical and the result, * matches everything
        result&= (pattern[i]== '*') ? true: value[i] == pattern[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

You can then call it like this:

```cs
bool b1 = PatternMatches("ABCDE***", "ABCDEFGH");
bool b2 = PatternMatches("ABC***", "ABCDEF");
```

You could use regular expressions, but this is fairly readable, RegExes aren't always.

Here is a link to a dotnetfiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/4x1U1E

Comment: Hi,  I tried this, it matches * for the char count, but it does not matches the characters which is not *. For Eg : If my pattern is 1BCDE*** and the value is ABCDEFGH it returns true. But if my pattern is ABCDE*** and the value is ABCDEFGHI, it returns false.

Comment: You must have made a copy paste error. I've made a DotNetFiddle and as you can see both your examples return false. Note: I've change `is` in line 20 to `==`. DotNetFiddle didn't like my `is`.

Comment: Hi Palle, it worked. I wrote = instead of &= in result. Thanks you for your help and time.

Comment: If you change `&=` to `=` it will only look at the last character. Otherwise change to `result= result & ((pattern[i]== '*') ? true: value[i] == pattern[i]);`

Answer (score 1):

Does this solve your requirements?

```
private static bool MatchesPattern(string input)
{
    const string fixedString = "ABCDExyz";
    return fixedString.Length == input.Length && fixedString.Substring(0, 5).Equals(input.Substring(0, 5));
}
```

In last versions of C# you can also use ranges:

```
private static bool MatchesPattern(string input)
{
    const string fixedString = "ABCDExyz";
    return fixedString.Length == input.Length && fixedString[..5].Equals(input[..5]);
}
```

See this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YqHL3G).

BTW: You could probably achieve the same using regex.

Comment: Hi, I tried this and it works in some cases. If my fixed string is ABCDExyzCB then it does not work because  the substring logic doesn't work.

Comment: The substring logic works. The method returns `false` for value `ABCDEFGH` (with fixed string `ABCDExyzCB`) because both strings differ in length. The method returns `true` for value `ABCDExyzXX`.

Comment: Hi Jan, made a mistake while typing. What I meant was it doesnt work when fixedString = "A*CDE***IJ" it returns false.

Comment: Here is the fiddle : https://dotnetfiddle.net/pE9ua6

Comment: Ah I see. Well, then my proposed answer won't work. In your original question you just mentioned that the _first_ n chars must match. Hence a StartsWith/Substring-logic does the trick. With this updated requirement you should probably look for a regex-solution.

Answer (score -1):

If the string you match against is known at compile time, your best bet is probably using regular expressions. In the first case, match against `^ABCDE...$`. In the second case, match against `^...DEF$`.

Another way, probably better if the match string is unknown, uses Length, StartsWith and EndsWith:

```
String prefix = "ABCDE";
if (str.Length == 8 && str.StartsWith(prefix)) {
    // do something
}
```

Then similarly for the second case, but using EndsWith instead of StartsWith.

Answer (score -1):

check this

```
public bool Comparing(string str1, string str2)
  => str2.StartWith(str1.replace("*","")) && str1.length == str2.Length;
```